# Do all php types return a bool?

Tags: php, types, isset, return-type

I'm currently building a website and I come across the case where I can do:

`if (myString)`

`if (myArray)`,

and it seems to "return" true whenever there is data inside the variable. At least, that's what I think.

E.g.

```
$testVar = "test";
if ($testVar)
    echo $testVar;
else
    echo "Empty";
```

When i assert `$testVar = ""`, then it echos "Empty".

I'm wondering if this is a defined feature of PHP, that any type will return true if it is not null or empty, as in other languages you need to do `if($testVar = "")` or so on.

Additionally, if this does indeed return true on all types if the variable is not empty, and I also want to check if the variable exists, would:

`if (isset($testVar) && $testVar)` be okay to use (in terms of practices)

I have searched for questions but can't find an answer to this exact question. To summarize:
Can any type return a bool, provided that it is not empty?

Thanks.

Comment: It might be helpful to read through the [PHP boolean docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), and probably [PHP type juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These types do not return true, but they are, instead, cast to true. PHP is a weak typed language, so it will automatically try to convert a variable to the correct type when required. In most instances, this means that a non-empty variable will return true.

This resource here will give you more information. Take a look at the "Converting to boolean" section, specifically.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Answer (score 1):

You can not check if a string is empty that way. Consider this:

```
$test = "0";
if ($test)
    echo $test;
else
    echo "Empty";
```

The code above prints "Empty", because "0" is a *falsy* value. See [Booleans](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), section "Converting to boolean".

So the answer is:
   All types can be converted to booleans, but the result might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

conditional always return bool 
if you need to check any empty values you need to use equalsto operator for check values

```
if($testVar == "") // check is $testVar is empty or not return bool-true/false
```

best to use functions like `empty()`

```
if(empty($testVar))
```

Comment: While that may be helpful advice, it doesn't really address the question.

Comment: Sure it does.  `empty` checks `isset` and `empty`.

Answer (score 0):

The variables don't "return" a bool, but any variable can evaluate to either true or false.

Best practice is to be strict on your comparisons and not just do `if($var)`

For detailed comparison information, see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 0):

In this example `when you are testing string variables`:

```
$testVar = "test";
if ($testVar)
    echo $testVar;
else
    echo "Empty";
```

What you are asserting is `if variable $testVar is set` (not if it's empty or not). The variable themselves don't have a return type, but it's in the context they are used in a control flow operator such as an `if` statement.

i.e. `if ($testVar)` is same as `if (isset($testVar))` (when $testVar is a string)

However, there are other cases like this:

```
$testVar = "0";
if ($testVar)
    echo $testVar;
else
    echo "Empty";
```

In this case, you will get "Empty" because `$testVar` is evaluated as a `int 0`.

However; if you had this:

```
$testVar = " 0"; // notice the space in front of 0
if ($testVar)
    echo $testVar;
else
    echo "Empty";
```

This will echo back the `$testVar` because the variable is both set and has a `string` value.

---

When you want to check for empty string, you have several options:

- `if (empty($testVar))`
- `if (strlen($testVar))` or `if (strlen($testVar) > 0)` (both same)

etc...

Comment: `if($testVar)` is NOT the same as `if(isset($testVar))`! If you set `$testVar = 0;` then `if($testVar)` evaluates to `false` while `isset($testVar)` returns `true`

Comment: My answer was based on the string test he was doing. He mentions nothing of evaluating boolean variables.

Comment: My comment mentions nothing of evaluating boolean variables. Your answer has misinformation in it: `if($var)` is not the same as `if(isset($var))`.

Comment: okay, answer clarified. Didn't mean to dish out misinformation lol.